# Troubles when I want to connect to another DB

Tags: database

I want to connect my Wordpress website 1 to database from Wordpress website 2.

Here is my code:

```
<?php

$myotherdatabase = new wpdb("username","password","databasename","localhost");

$motscles = "abri";

$query = "SELECT `post_id` FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE `meta_key` = 'nom' AND MATCH (`meta_value`) AGAINST ('" . $motscles . "' IN BOOLEAN MODE)";

$result = $myotherdatabase -> get_results($query, ARRAY_A);

foreach ($result as $post) {
  $pids .= $post['post_id'] . ",";// ARRAY_A
}

echo $pids;

?>
```

The result is empty.
If I run the same query directly on Wordpress website 2, it works.

Therre is something wrong in my code?
Or do you think the problem may come from hosting?

Thank you

---

EDIT: The problem came from the hosting. There is a restriction, I can not connect to the website 2 database from website 1.

Comment: Do you run the same script, or just the SELECT query in phpMyAdmin e.g. on your website 2? Is the 'wp_' prefix correct in website 2?

Answer (score 0):

Use code as below :

```
<?php

$myotherdatabase = new wpdb("username","password","databasename","localhost");

$motscles = "abri";

$query = "SELECT `post_id` FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE `meta_key` = 'nom' AND MATCH (`meta_value`) AGAINST ('" . $motscles . "' IN BOOLEAN MODE)";

$result = $myotherdatabase -> get_results($query, ARRAY_A);

foreach ($result as $post) {
  $pids .= $post->post_id . ",";// ARRAY_A
}

echo $pids;

?>
```